# Resizing an image in React Native with resizeMode="contain" moves it

Tags: react-native

I have this image:
[image]
which has a height of 160 (!) but is pretty long (~2000). I created the following app:

```js
const wave3 = require('./res/wave3.png');

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image
        style={{
          height: 160,
        }}
        resizeMode="contain"
        source={wave3}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Note that I entered a height of 160, which is the same as the image height. The results are expected:
[image]
Now, if I set a height lower than 160, the image moves to the right:
[image]
*`height: 130`*

and for higher than 160, it moves down (at a slower rate):
[image]
*`height: 190`*

Is this expected behavior? Why isn't the image scaling as it is described in the docs for `resizeMode="contain"`?

Comment: I think you better specify the width of the image, uses `style={{height: 160, width: '100%'}}` should be fine.

Comment: I would like to understand what makes it move, though. Since there is no padding or left/right/top/bottom specifications in my code it feels weird and wrong.

Comment: In [RN docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode) about resizeMode: contain, `Scale the image uniformly so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view`. I think the width of your container is undefined, therefore it will ignore the bounding of width.